# Efficient way to simultaneously calc AVG and stddev_pop in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

stddev_pop() must be calculating AVG() as part of the full calc of standard deviation (unless there's a shortcut I'm unaware of).

for context, the goal is to test for the difference of means between the these two geom columns.

Is there any way to access that in order to avoid recalculating AVG()?

here's an example query:

```
select 
    avg(st_length(cons.geom)) as source_avg_length,
    avg(st_length(csn.geom)) as target_avg_length,
    stddev_pop(st_length(cons.geom)) as source_std_length,
    stddev_pop(st_length(csn.geom)) as target_std_length
from 
    received.conflation_osm_no_service cons,
    received.conflation_stress_network csn ;
```

and the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` which makes me think that if I ask for avg() and stddev_pop() it will only do the avg() calc once and reuse it?:

[image: explain analyze]

Comment: `stddev_pop()` does not need to calculate intermediate averages.  There are many ways to arrive at the same calculation.

Comment: Your query is doing a cross join of 11645 x 14380= 167455100 rows. Is there no any other algorithm to calculate these numbers than generatiing 167 millions rows, store them in memory and/or on disk, scan the whole resultset and calculate averages ? Generation this cross join and then scanning it are the most costly operations, doing an average twice  is only a minimal overhead.

Comment: you're right @krokodilko, I calculated each table's stats in a separate query and it's nearly instant. Is it obvious why the two tables were joined in the original query? Seems like an unnecessary step.

Comment: Why are you creating a cross join between the two tables? Shouldn't you use a `JOIN` instead? But as long as you don't have a WHERE clause, the Seq Scan will be the only sensible option as you want all rows from both tables.

Comment: I didn't realize that the query would be executed that way, there's no reason that I can't simply do the queries separately and then join the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine both tables in a single result you must aggregate before joining:

```
select *
from 
 (  
   select 
       avg(st_length(geom)) as source_avg_length,
       stddev_pop(st_length(geom)) as source_std_length
   from received.conflation_osm_no_service cons
 ) as src
cross join
 (
   select 
       avg(st_length(geom)) as target_avg_length,
       stddev_pop(st_length(geom)) as target_std_length,
   from 
       received.conflation_stress_network csn ;
 ) as tgt
```

or to get one row per table:

```
select 'source' as tablename,
    avg(st_length(geom)) as avg_length,
    stddev_pop(st_length(geom)) as std_length
from 
    received.conflation_osm_no_service cons

union all

select 'target',
    avg(st_length(geom)),
    stddev_pop(st_length(geom)),
from 
    received.conflation_stress_network csn ;
```

Answer (score 0):

per the comments, I was attributing slow execution times to multiple average aggregations when in reality it was due to an unnecessary join.